# How to remove Spacing Between Navigation Menu Items?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS3 and  HTML5. I want to know how can I remove spacing between my navigation bar buttons.

My HTMLCode is:

```
<nav id="menu"> 
            <ul>
                <li>
                GET HELICOPTER TOURS</li><li>
                GET PARTY BUS</li><li>
                GET BUS TICKET</li><li>
                GET BUS TOURS</li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
```

And my CSS3 code is:

```
    #menu li{
    position:relative;
    font: bold 14px Tahoma;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float:right;
    margin-right:100px;
    margin-top:35px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: just remove the `margin-right:100px` and they wont have any margin between them. or put some small margin value.

Comment: Yes, reducing margin values will help you

Comment: Thank you. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Fmqf/1/)

```
ul li{

    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do:-

```
display:inline;
margin-right:10px;
```

margin can be adjusted according to your requirement